# Openshift outdated python packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, openshift, pypi

I use free gear on openshift.com, I need to install SQLAlchemy 1.0+, but openshift use local easy_install mirror for downloading packages and latest version of SQLAlchemy is 0.7.9. i try to using pip, but it also use local mirror.
Then i find this solution, but compiling process crash.
`--index-url https://pypi.python.org/simple/`

In requirements.txt and had problem with permissions(to cache folder and to other that used by pip).
How i can get fresh packages from pypi?

Answer (score 1):

Try

1) SSH into your app

2) activate your venv

```
source  python/virtenv/venv/bin/activate
```

3) Manually install package

```
easy_install sqlalchemy==1.0
```